# C11 implicit conversion of chars, x % y

Tags: c

In C11,

```c
char foo(char x, char y) {
    return x % y;
}
```

Is any implicit conversion (e.g. promotion to int) done anywhere?

Comment: [Usual arithmetic conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) is happening. Perhaps you can elaborate on *why* you're asking this? What problem do you really have?

Comment: Alo, to add, `....The operands of the % operator shall
have integer type.`..so, integer promotion rule applies.

Comment: `sizeof (x % y)` should give a hint.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, the usual arithmetic conversion says that "If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.", so the answer is *nothing happens*?

Comment: @sinelaw Check case 4 in the linked reference: "First of all, both operands undergo *integer promotions*". The "if the types are same" is *after* the promotion.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yeah, I missed that part. So the answer is "the operands are converted to int (or unsigned int) in x % y"

Comment: As a follow up question about -Wconversion in GCC, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795474/why-does-gccs-wconversion-behave-differently-for-char-vs-unsigned-char

Comment: Basically the code is equivalent to `return (char)((int)x % (int)y);`

Comment: @Lundin Good eye - 3 conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usual arithmetic conversions apply to operands of `%` the same way they apply to operands of other multiplicative and additive operators (see [*6.5.5 Multiplicative operators*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p3)).

The operands are promoted either to `int` or to `unsigned int`, depending on the range of `char` type on your platform (see [*6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) and [*6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2))

On most real-life platforms, the operands will be promoted to `int`, since range of `int` typically covers the full range of `char`. On a more-or-less exotic platform where `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)` and `char` is an unsigned type (implying that range of `char` does not fit into range of `int`), they will be promoted to `unsigned int`.

Comment: `sizeof(char) = 1` in any implementation.

Comment: @alinsoar: Yes, that's true. And what point are you trying to make? What I said above would imply that it is possible to have `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int) == 1`. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @alinsoar: I don't immediately see the relevance or importance of that fact in this context.

Comment: forget it, it's ok.

Comment: did you see any machine where sizeof(int) = 1 ?  How can you figure any such machine ?

Comment: @alinsoar: C implementations for embedded platforms on TI (Texas Instruments) CPUs typically have that property. It is fairly exotic at first sight, but that's something C language was designed for from day one. I don't see any problems "figuring" it. Why?

Comment: This is the most correct answer so far... can you quote the sections in the standard? In draft N1570, they are 6.5.5 (%), 6.3.1.8 (usual arithmetic conversion) and 6.3.1.1 (integer promotion)

Comment: @alinsoar: See this one, for example, http://downloads.ti.com/docs/esd/SPRU514/index.html#SPRU514N_HTML/tms320c28x-c-c-language-implementation.html#STDZ0555922

Comment: suppose you have a machine with the size of char = 16 bits and size of int = 20 bits.  How can you know the sizeof(int) ?

Comment: and a little comment -- not all the time it is promoted to int as I answered, if the interpreter can prove the result will be the same, no need to compute it via coercions.

Comment: @alinsoar: In C the idea is to use the minimal addressable memory unit as `char`. If your machine's minimal addressable memory unit has 16 bits, that would imply that the next larger type will have at least 32 bits in it. The only way to have a "20 bit `int`" on such machine would be to reserve two bytes for it (32 bits, `sizeof(int) == 2`) and then reserve 12 bits as unused padding bits.

Comment: I thought the same -- I think this happens actually on some machines, on some such machines `the padding` space can generate trap representations, so the padding should be taken in consideration by the interpreter, sometimes.

Comment: @alinsoar: Whatever language features exist in C, they all are subject to the well-known "as if" optimization rule. All language features are conceptual. C compilers are not required to implement them literally. C compilers are only supposed to reproduce the required observable behavior. As long as the observable behavior is correct, compilers are allowed to perform this calculation without promotions. This is understood without saying, which is why we don't normally mention it in each and every answer.

Answer (score 2):

The requirement for the operands of `%` operator is
n1570-§6.5.5(p2):

> The operands of the `%` operator shall have integer type

In this case usual arithmetic conversion will take place on both operands as `char` is promoted to `unsigned int`.

Comment: *"char is promoted to int"* Or `unsigned int`. Size and signedness of `char` matters.

Comment: Right. Specifically 6.5.5 says "The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.", and 6.3.1.8 on *that* says "the integer promotions are performed on both operands...", which means they are expanded to int in this case.

Comment: @sinelaw; Yes. Promotions will be performed on both operands.

Comment: ``char is promoted to int Or unsigned int`` -- indeed, this is very subtle.