# Why does GCC's -Wconversion behave differently for char vs. unsigned char?

Tags: c, gcc

Consider

```c
U8 foo(U8 x, U8 y) {
    return x % y;
}
```

GCC's -Wconversion behaves differently if U8, the type of x and y, is char or unsigned char:

`gcc -Wconversion -c test.c -DU8='unsigned char'`

(no warning)

```
gcc -Wconversion -c test.c -DU8=char
test.c: In function ‘foo’:
test.c:2:14: warning: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
     return x % y;
            ~~^~~
```

But [from what I understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795026/c11-implicit-conversion-of-chars-x-y) in both cases x, y undergo integer promotion (to int or unsigned int) and so in both cases it will be converting from int to whatever the return type is (char or unsigned char).

Why is there a difference?

Bonus question: if you enable ubsan (-fsanitize=undefined) then GCC emits -Wconversion in both cases.

**EDIT**:

There is no argument that x, y undergo integer promotion and then need to be converted to the result type, so no need to explain that.

The only question here is *why does GCC behave differently* for different types. The answer will involve some insight on GCC's internals.

Comment: In second case, I guess, you can loose the sign of the result.

Comment: @LPs how so? You mean if int is signed and char is unsigned? But AFAIK in my GCC, char is signed and so is int. Or do you mean something else

Comment: I have a feeling the warnings are not *wrong*, but that GCC does not analyze the situation fully. @LP the sign should always be positive in this case right? But GCC does not "know" this or any other "backtracking" info at the time it warns, by then it only knows it is an `int` converted to a `char`, and an `int` can hold larger values than a `char`. So GCC warns.

Comment: @Prof. Falken: No, the sign is not always positive. C implements Fortran division, not Euclidean division. Operator `/` rounds towards zero, and `%` is forced to follow the suit. E.g. `-5 % 2 = -1`

Comment: @Prof.FalkenYes,  is what I meant, [tag:gcc] "thinks" you can loose sign or values due to range change. BTW the sign can be negative, because of `%` is `reminder operator` in [tag:c] not `modulus`, so the sign is the same of the dividend.

Comment: @LPs, @AnT, oh, today I learned about `%`. Haha, after so many years. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR

using information only about the types involved, `gcc` should warn for both cases because of conversion from `int` (larger type) to `char`/`unsigned char` (smaller types)

Using also information about the possible values (range analysis) `gcc` should warn for none because the result of `x % y`, even after promotions to int, will always fit back to the same type as `x` and `y`.

So it seems that in the first case `gcc` can assert that the operations will never result in a value change, but for some reason cannot do that for the second case.

As a side note, clang does not warn for any.

---

### Type system

- On the tested system (x86-64) the `char` type is signed. Please be aware that it still a different type than `signed char`.
- `x % y` Due to integer promotion rules, in both cases, `x` and `y` are promoted to `int`. The result `x % y` is of type `int`.
- If we make all the implicit conversions explicit then we get this:

  ```
  unsigned char foo1(unsigned char x, unsigned char y)
  {
     return (unsigned char)((int) x % (int) y);
  }

  char foo2(char x, char y)
  {
     return (char)((int) x % (int) y);
  }
  ```
- Implicit conversion from `int` to `char`, `unsigned char` and to `signed char` fires the warning with `-Wconversion`:

  > -Wconversion
  >
  > Warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value. This includes
  >   [..] and conversions to smaller types

  Indeed both these functions result in a warning getting generated:

  ```
  char bar1(int a)
  {
     return a; // warning: conversion from 'int' to 'char' may change value [-Wconversion]
  }

  unsigned char bar2(int a)
  {
     return a;  // warning: conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned char' may change value [-Wconversion]
  }
  ```

So using type information only we should get a warning for both because our 2 functions have an implicit conversion from `int` to `char`/`unsigned char` just like `bar1` and `bar2`.

### Value analysis

If we use the notation `r = x % y` then `r` has the same sign as `x` and `|r| ∈ [0, |y|)`.

- if `x` and `y` are of type `unsigned char` then `r ∈ [0, CHAR_MAX)`.

  `r` fits in an `unsigned char`. So no warning needed.
- if `x` and `y` are of type `char`:

  - `CHAR_MIN = -CHAR_MAX - 1`
  - `max(|y|) = CHAR_MAX + 1`
  - `|r| ∈ [0, max(|y|))`
  - `|r| ∈ [0, CHAR_MAX + 1)`
  - `r ∈ (-CHAR_MAX - 1, CHAR_MAX + 1)`

  `r` fits in a `char` so no warning needed.

So what I am arguing is that **the result of `x % y` always fits in an `U8`** even after all the integer promotions and implicit conversions.

---

You can have a look at this [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/67Eb7q)

Comment: Thanks! I agree on all points, which leaves the question unanswered: why does GCC get confused in one case but not the other case.

Comment: @sinelaw as you can see the analysis for `char` is more complicated that for `unsigned char` in this case. I can only speculate that the algorithm either does not deal with this situation or it does not go deep enough on the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, `x % y` involves implicit type conversion of both operands to `int` (the integer promotion rule/the usual arithmetic conversions). The result of the operation is type `int`.

`-Wconversion` is concerned about implicit changes of signedness in an expression, since those might possibly be unintended. It gives warnings when you convert between signed and unsigned type without an explicit cast. It also apparently warns against potential issues with overflow, when implicitly converting from a larger type (signed or unsigned) to a smaller one.

(The `char` type has implementation-defined signedness, it may be either unsigned or signed. GCC likes to make it signed in all implementations I've seen. )

An implicit conversion from `int` to `char` may lead to overflow of the `char`.

We can silence the compiler by writing `return (char)(x % y);`. This only hides away the potential bug though. You have to ensure in your code that the overflow can never happen before adding such an explicit cast.